# Chrome image does not show

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a strange problem where an image does not show up in chrome but it shows just fine in firefox. When i look at the html code the complete and correct pathway is there but no image is displayed. Same pathway is in firefox and the image shows just fine.

When I right click the chrome image placeholder to download the image from chrome I can see the file name but when i click download it chrome gives me "There is no file".

Comment: Is this a single specific image that isn't being displayed, or is it all images? Can you please give us a link to the offending image?

Comment: Can you show us the code for the img tag that isn't working?

Comment: I solved it very stupid mistake on my end. Thanks for all the answers though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your chrome settings. allows images to be displayed. 
go to - `chrome://chrome/settings/content`, in image section, allow images to be displayed

Answer (score 0):

What is the path of the image you wrote in

```
<img src=" ">
```

?

You probably typed it in a non-standardized way...

Comment: This would probably make a better comment than answer.